# 英語が残っている: メタタグ、権限獲得の際の "You can now"、および Community のユーザー名

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

Apologies for this not being in Japanese. The "You can now" string isn't translated, nor are the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), or other standard mod tags.

Also, [Community](/users/-1)'s name isn't translated either. The screenshot is below.

---

この投稿の翻訳：

日本語でなくてすいません。"You can now" の文字列が翻訳されておらず、また、[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) や [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) などのモデレータータグも翻訳されていません。

また、ユーザー [Community](/users/-1) の名前も翻訳されていません。以下はスクリーンショットです。

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: モデレータータグについて: 確かに [スペイン語版](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)、[ロシア語版](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)、[ポルトガル語版](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags)では翻訳されているようです。

Comment: Communityについて: [スペイン語版](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad)、[ロシア語版](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)、[ポルトガル語版](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade)ではユーザー名や説明文などが翻訳されているようです。

Comment: transifex では hit しないので、翻訳されている系の文字じゃなさそうです。 ちょっと確認します。。

Answer (score 1):

#### You can now

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/114992873

上の transifex の様子です。画像を見るかぎり、「これによって以下が行えます」がいいのではないか、と思っています。

#### status-xxx

おそらく、これに該当する翻訳はまだないので、文面を決めて変更のリクエストをするのがいいのではないか、と思っています。

- status-completed : ステータス-完了
- status-planned: ステータス-対応予定
- status-deferred: ステータス-延期
- status-bydesign: 。うまい訳が思いつかない。
- status-review: ステータス-レビュー
- status-reproduced: ステータス-再現済
- status-declined: ステータス-却下
- status-norepro: ステータス-未再現

のように、翻訳を行ってみましたが、いかがでしょうか。

#### Community

これも同様にリクエストを出すパターンだと思っています。 [メインユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) では翻訳があるので、これを meta にも再現するのがいいと思っています。

Comment: 『bydesign』は『仕様』が似合うと思います。

Comment: @YukiInoue モデレータータグを「ステータス-xxx」の形に訳すべきか判断しかねています。ハイフン記号は英語における単語分かち書きのデリミタとして機能しているのだと思いますが、日本語は単語を分かち書きしません。現状和訳されているタグもハイフンを消しているように思います。とはいえ良い案を思いつきません……。

Comment: 結局良い案を思いついていません。「ステータス-xxx」が現状最善ですね。