# 状況を示すメタサイトのモデレーター専用タグは英語にするべきか

Tags: 討議, 英語, タグ

このサイトを全Stack Exchangeサイトの調査や統計に参加させるために、モデレーター専用タグ名を英語にするべきでしょうか？

Stack Exchange社のサイト群にはそれぞれメタサイトが有り、そこに寄せられた要望などの対応状況を記録するためのタグが有ります。これらはモデレーター専用タグと呼ばれ、どのサイトでも同じ名前が付けられています。ただし、このサイト（日本語版）では翻訳されており、元の英語のタグ名は別名という扱いです。

英語のタグ名と日本語のタグ名の対応は下のようになっています。

- [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) - [仕様](/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%95%e6%a7%98)
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - [完了](/questions/tagged/%e5%ae%8c%e4%ba%86)
- [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - [却下](/questions/tagged/%e5%8d%b4%e4%b8%8b)
- [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) - [延期](/questions/tagged/%e5%bb%b6%e6%9c%9f)
- [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) - [再現性なし](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%80%a7%e3%81%aa%e3%81%97)
- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) - [対応予定](/questions/tagged/%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c%e4%ba%88%e5%ae%9a)
- [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) - [再現済](/questions/tagged/%e5%86%8d%e7%8f%be%e6%b8%88)
- [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) - [調査中](/questions/tagged/%e8%aa%bf%e6%9f%bb%e4%b8%ad)

この日本語のタグ名は日本語話者にとっては解り易くて良いのですが、問題も有りそうだと気付きました。困るのは、Stack Exchange社が調査や統計を行なう際に疎外される可能性が高いということです。

例えば、Stack Exchange社ではエスカレーションされて「status-review」タグが付与された質問を追跡しています。それらに対する応答率に目標を設定し、[四半期毎に結果が報告されています](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/what-posts-should-be-escalated-to-staff-using-status-review-and-how-do-i-esca/388089#388089)。しかし、それにはこのサイトは含まれていないと思われます。タグ名が異なるため、使用されている[SQLクエリー](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1245452/posts-with-status-review-network-wide)では日本語版の投稿がマッチしないためです

（追記: 上のクエリーは修正されました。詳細は[nekketsuuuさんの投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392727/sql-query-used-to-calculate-staff-escalation-statistics-doesnt-take-into-accoun)をご覧ください。）

このように、日本語版の状況がStack Exchange社から不可視になるのを防ぐため、モデレーター専用タグ名を英語に変更するべきでしょうか？ （この場合、日本語のタグ名を別名にできますが、表示は常に英語になるはずです）

Comment: (過去の他の投稿でも使用されていますが) 「公式タグ」という表現は語弊がある気がします。モデレータータグについては **コミュニティモデレーター** も付与する場合があり、「公式タグ = すべて SE 社オフィシャルな見解」というイメージを持たれてしまうようだと困ります。 / 「モデレーターが社員相当の権限を持っている」ではなく、「社員も便宜上モデレーター権限を使用している」の方が実態に近いです。

Comment: ところで https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1245452/posts-with-status-review-network-wide の SQL が international sites 対応していないのはびっくりなので MSE で報告したいですね……。mjy さんなさいますか？　ご面倒であれば自分やっちゃいます。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 私は当分報告する予定はないです。よろしくお願いします。
日本語タグを使い続けたいという意見にもう少し票が集まってからそれも含めて伝える、という手もあると思います。

Comment: 以前の投稿を含め、タグ種の表現を「モデレーター専用タグ」に統一しました。

Comment: @mjy 承知です。この投稿の賛否に関わらず ja.SO 以外の international sites も影響を受けていそうなので自分の方で報告しておきます。

Comment: 報告しました〜 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392727/341401

Answer (score 3):

日本語のままで良いと考えています。システムとして用意されているタグにはモデレータータグの他に [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) などの質問カテゴリを示すタグもあり、これらは [バグ](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0) 等に和訳されています。分析用途という意味だと質問カテゴリのタグも英語のほうが他サイトと揃いはしますが、日本語話者の使いやすさと読みやすさを考えると日本語のままが良いでしょう。同じことがモデレータータグにも言えると思います。

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) に対する分析が公開されているのは [What posts should be escalated to staff using [status-review], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/341401) の冒頭にまとまっている議論が過去あったためです。このような機会はあまり無いはずで、何かしらクエリ等に問題を見つけたら都度問題を報告するので充分そうです。

モデレータータグの名前が翻訳されているのは他の international sites でも同様なので、ja.SO だけ英語に戻しても他の international sites では依然として問題が残ってしまいます。問題を報告して全 international sites が恩恵を受けられるようにした方が Stack Exchange 全体としては良さそうです。

Answer (score 3):

利用者の利便性の観点から[英語が残っている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2626)タグを[日本語に直した](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3061)経緯がありますので、統計など運営側のメリットのためにタグを英語に戻すのはあまり賛同したくありません。

タグ変更の提案をした際には`status-bydesign`の翻訳に苦労し、英語の苦手な私は他のタグについても意味が分かっていないことを再認識しました。
利用頻度の低いユーザにとっては英語タグが表示され、クリックして別名を表示しないと意味が把握しにくい状況は現在の日本語タグよりも歓迎しにくいユーザが多いのではないかと感じています。
(もちろん根拠はない推測にすぎないのですが)

またざっと見渡した限りでは、他言語の姉妹サイトでは完全にせよ不完全にせよ翻訳されている例が多いように見受けられます。
姉妹サイトの翻訳経緯は存じませんが、SOjaのみ公式タグを英語に寄せなくても良いように思うのが私個人の意見です。

- [ポルトガル語](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) : `status-`が残っていたり`destaque`のように残っていなかったりする
- [スペイン語](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/) : 接頭辞が`estado-`に置き換わっている
- [ロシア語](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/) : 完全に翻訳されている

英語化の主な目的がSQLクエリーに対応させることであればSQLと運用でカバーすることはできないでしょうか。
思い付きですが、例えば`調査中`を`status-調査中`に書き換えるなど検索に合わせたプレフィックスを追加して、さらにSQL側で`status-`の後ろが英語タグにマッチしない場合は別名を取ってきて英語タグを取得するようSQLを改修できれば目的を達成できそうに思います。
あくまでも対応案の一例です。この場合はタグを若干加工することになります。
※例示したものの個人的に現在のタグを気に入ってるので、心情的にプレフィックス追加案はモヤッとします。

Comment: pt.SO の [destaque] tag は status- 系のタグではなくて [featured]、日本語だと [注目] タグのことみたいです。タグの別名になっていました https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/destaque/synonyms